# Onclick Listener for OK button

Tags: android, dialog

This is my code for creating a Dialog Box

```
public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        try { 
            Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title1);
            dialog.setMessage(R.string.url);
            dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, null);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add an EventListener to setPositiveButton (the OK button). When OK is clicked, my application should be closed i.e. the user should exit from app. Can anyone help me achieving this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    MyActivity.this.finish();         
  }
});
```

Comment: If you pass your activity to your dialog. You can call finish to close your app.

Comment: Like someone else has answered, inside your onClick() call MyActivity.this.finish();

Comment: what should i do to go to another layout by clicking OK. I know i shold use Intent for that. But i want to know what uis the xact code for that @BlackRider

Comment: Hey, post another question for that and send me the link if you want. This is getting too big for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("XYZ")
        .setMessage("Do you want to Exit ?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                MyActivityClass.this.finish();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        }
        })
        .setNeutralButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();                   
            }
            })          
        .create()
        .show();
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this code**

```
Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Message");
        dialog.setMessage("Exit App?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Enter your Code for exit Application
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog ad1=new AlertDialog.Builder(Hangman.this).create();
            ad1.setMessage("You want to Exit");
            ad1.setCancelable(false);
            ad1.setButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HomeActivity.this.finish();

                }
            });
```

Try this one.. :)
Updated

Comment: System.exit(0) is not a nice way to end an application. Please take some time to control what activities have you opened and call finish() when no longer needed. A nice FSM of your opened activities might help.

Comment: Yes @MarBar I agreed with you..Thanks.